# Redirecionar serviço Rest com .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, apache, slim

Eu tenho uma pasta no meu projeto chamada `api`, e dentro dela um arquivo `.htaccess` que deveria redirecionar os *requests* (feitos via jquery) para a pasta `app/controllers/rest/` que também possui um arquivo `.htaccess` e um arquivo chamado `endpoint.php`, onde os *requests* são tratados e onde ocorre a interação com o *framework* Slim.

O arquivo .htaccess da pasta `api`, possui os seguintes parâmetros:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../app/controllers/rest/$1 [QSA]
```

O arquivo `.htaccess` da pasta `app/controllers/rest/`, possui os seguintes parâmetros:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ endpoint.php [QSA,L]
```

E o arquivo `endpoint.php` possui o seguinte código:

```
$app = new \app\libs\Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/foo', function () {
   echo '{"teste": "TESTE"}';
});
$app->run();
```

Ao fazer um *request* para url `app/controllers/rest/foo`, o mesmo retorna o resultado, no entanto se o *request* for feito usando a url `api/foo`, o framework não consegue identificar o parâmetro `/foo`.

Obs.: Estou trabalhando em ambiente Linux/ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de vários testes de tentativa e erro descobri que o direcionamento por `.htaccess` deve ser feito com o endereço completo. Primeiro tentei redirecionar com o código `HTTP 301` (`[R=301,L]`), mas percebi que ao direcionar a pagina o mesmo tratava como `GET` todos os tipos de `request` (`POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`). Pesquisando na internet descobri que alterando o código `HTTP` para `300` (`[R=300,L]`), o redirecionamento funciona perfeitamente para qualquer método. O arquivo `.htaccess` da pasta `api` ficou assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/app/Controllers/rest/$1 [R=300,L]
```

O arquivo `.htaccess` da pasta`app/controllers/rest/`, não precisou ser alterado.